# Shoutcast get metadata XMLHttpRequest cors

Tags: xmlhttprequest, shoutcast

I am trying to read this Shoutcast metadata with XMLHttpRequest:
http://cast10.plugstreaming.com:8002/stats?sid=1&json=1

When I try this I get "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.". I already have cors, so why does it throw that error?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
     console.error(xhr.statusText);
};
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
           
};

var url = 'https://kastproxy-us.herokuapp.com/' + 'http://cast10.plugstreaming.com:8002/stats?sid=1&json=1'

xhr.open("GET", url, true); 

xhr.send();
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  Make sure you're using your proxy URL.  If you use the URL directly that you show, it isn't going to work because SHOUTcast doesn't support the necessary headers for CORS.

Comment: How could I read this metadata then? It doesnt have to be with cors.

Comment: I don't know... as I said, what you show is working for me.